# Getting a value of a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I got an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [Product_1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 123.00
        )

    [Product_2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 456.00
        )

)
```

What I would like to do if it's possible is something like this

```
$arr['Product_1']['price']
```

and then that will print out the price of product_1 and if I do

```
$arr['Product_2']['price']
```

it will print out product_2 price.

The reason why I would like to do something like this is so that I can compare product 1 and product 2, because what I need to do is grab the price of both of them and compare it against each other.

What happens at the moment is even if I do

```
$arr['Product_2']['price']
```

I get this error

```
Undefined index: Product_2
```

Here is my code

```
$arr = [];
foreach($products as $productCode => $product)
{
    $arr[$productCode] = ([
                        'price' => $product->price
                    ]);


    dd($arr['Product_2']['price'])''
}
```

Comment: is this a question, because you are right

Comment: @JovylleBermudez - Sorry about that. I've updated my question. Let me know if that helps or if I need to reword it

Comment: If you get that error, then your array did not actually contain what you said it does, at least not at this specific point in the script.

Comment: If so then there are some hidden characters or something, try `var_dump(array_keys($arr));`

Comment: @AbraCadaver -   I got this when I `var_dump(array_keys($arr));`  
```array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Product_1"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Product_1"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Product_2"
}
```

Comment: I also updated my question to have my foreach loop

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `echo $products['Product_2']->price;` or `echo $products->Product_2->price;` whichever it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `$arr['Product_2']['price']` inside your `foreach` loop, PHP will try to access the second element before it has been actually defined.

Call the last line `dd($arr['Product_2']['price']);` after the loop has finished parsing the `$products` array and the warning will not appear anymore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped me out so much.

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!